# Save "Title" item to ListView and click on item to load data to new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, save

I am creating an app where in an activity the user inputs a class name (ex: Geology 101) and underneath, there are edittexts where the user inputs an assignment(Homeworks) and it's corresponding grade weight(15%). And when the user saves this I want the name of the class to be stored to the listview in another activity. So when the user looks at his schedule he sees, Geology 101 and when he clicks that item it shows the various assignment types such as Homeworks, Tests, Quizzes etc and you can then click Homework and here you'll have stored the various homeworks inputted through another activity.

This is what I have for the activity with my various edittext's so far.

new_class.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/register_assign_edit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:hint="@string/example_assign"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:inputType="textCapWords"
         android:layout_weight="1">
     </EditText>

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/register_weight_edit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/example_weight"
         android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:singleLine="true">
     </EditText>        

</LinearLayout>
```

new_class_container.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_gray">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/register_class_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/write_class_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_class_edit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/example_name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_assign_textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/write_assignment_type"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4169E1"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/register_weight_textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/write_assign_percent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#4169E1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/register_assign_edit"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:hint="@string/example_assign"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:inputType="textCapWords"
             android:layout_weight="1">
         </EditText>

        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/register_weight_edit"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="@string/example_weight"
             android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:inputType="number"
             android:singleLine="true">
         </EditText>        

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:onClick="onAddNewClicked"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/more_assign"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

new_class.java

```
public class NewClass extends Activity{

    private LinearLayout mContainerView;

    private Button mAddButton;


    private View mExclusiveEmptyView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_class_container);

        mContainerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentView);

        mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);       
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public void onAddNewClicked(View v){
        inflateEditRow(null, null);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

//Inflates the new_class xml each time I press the Add New Button

    private void inflateEditRow(String name, String name1){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_class, null);

        final EditText register_assign = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.register_assign_edit);
        final EditText et1 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.register_weight_edit);

        if (name != null && !name.isEmpty() && name1 != null && !name1.isEmpty()) {
            register_assign.setText(name);
            et1.setText(name1);
        } else {
            mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
        }

        register_assign.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    mAddButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (mExclusiveEmptyView != null
                            && mExclusiveEmptyView != rowView) {
                        mContainerView.removeView(mExclusiveEmptyView);
                    }
                    mExclusiveEmptyView = rowView;
                } else {

                    if (mExclusiveEmptyView == rowView) {
                        mExclusiveEmptyView = null;
                    }

                    mAddButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }
        });


        mContainerView.addView(rowView, mContainerView.getChildCount()-1);
    }
// Add save button to action bar        
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.btn_save:
                //make it save to the new activity
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }

    }
}
```

[image: This is how the new_class_container looks]

So each time I press the Add More button the new_class layout inflates right underneath. And as you can see in my code the save button is in the action bar and I want to click that and store the data in the method mentioned above. I was wondering how I can assign the specific weight to the specific assignment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, are you required to do this way(inflate a new view into the container)? or you just simply go with ListView, just add new Item, refresh the view and it's there. You can take a look at this example:

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button add;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                data.add("Add new item and its properties, class name, assignment type, grade...");
                // Here you can store into your data storage(database,etc) to display later
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private ArrayList<String> data;

        public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            View view = arg1;
            if(view == null){
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
```

And the XML
Container:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
         >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Add more" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name of class:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Asignment Type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Grade Weight(%)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.